# SAS Datasets used in the Course 'Predictive Modeling using Logistic Regression'

Tags: dataset, sas, regression, logistic-regression

I am looking to rework through the examples in the SAS course 'Predictive Modeling using Logistic Regression (https://support.sas.com/edu/schedules.html?ctry=us&id=2677). I am unable to find my copy of the datasets used in the book though and they don't seem to be available for download either. Does anyone have a copy of the datasets?

Comment: What are the names of the datasets in question? Presumably they're not available in the `sashelp` library?

Comment: The raw data is in a file 'INS.dat' and that is read into 'develop.sas7bdat'. No, I didn't find that in `sashelp` library.

Comment: You should send an email to your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data isn't available for public download.  But, there is a page where people who purchased the course notes can request a download of the course data and code.  I assume this would apply for people who paid for the course as well:  http://support.sas.com/training/forms/data .

If that doesn't work and you haven't heard back from the instructor, I would suggest you contact SAS support.  I'm sure they can get you to the data, or to the person who can get you the data.